# What is the difference between “(Noun) + 側” and “(Noun)”?

Tags: word-choice

This is a question that I have been trying to figure out. I have two sentences (as well as variations and translations) that I would like to cite, but before I do so, I should provide the context first.

A woman was letting her oldest daughter (three years old) play in a public park. But she wound up being hounded by a man accusing her daughter of shoving his son. The man even went so far as to call the police, which resulted in six police officers rushing into the park. The police officers, having already decided who the guilty party was, brought only the woman and her daughter to the nearest police station for a voluntary interview and interviewed them for approximately two and a half hours. The woman and her daughter denied that she shoved him, but the police told them to confess to assault.

Now that I have provided the context, I will cite the two sentences, variations and translations.

> 1.(a)…【男性側】に連絡先の電話番号を伝えることに同意するまで帰してもらえなかった。
>
> …They could not get them to let them go home until she agreed to giving her contact phone number to the **man’s side**.
>
> 1.(b)…【男性】に連絡先の電話番号を伝えることに同意するまで帰してもらえなかった。
>
> …They could not get them to let them go home until she agreed to giving her contact phone number to the **man**.
>
> 2.(a)【警察側】は後日、民事訴訟を起こすとする男性に女性と長女の氏名や年齢、住所などの個人情報を伝達。
>
> At a later date, the **police side** transferred personal information such as the names, ages and addresses of the woman and her oldest daughter to the man, who alleged that he would file a civil lawsuit.
>
> 2.(b)【警察】は後日、民事訴訟を起こすとする男性に女性と長女の氏名や年齢、住所などの個人情報を伝達。
>
> At a later date, the **police** transferred personal information such as the names, ages and addresses of the woman and her oldest daughter to the man, who alleged that he would file a civil lawsuit.

With the context and sentences in mind, is there a difference between 男性側 and 男性 as well as 警察側 and 警察? If so, what might that be?

By the way, I came up with the above scenario from the following article.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210705192709/https://www.nikkansports.com/general/news/202107050001193.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

男性側 implies that there is someone or a team working for or representing "him". You can tell something to a lawyer working for the man and say 男性側に伝えた. Even if you have talked to the man directly, if you expect he will consult someone else (so you are indirectly telling them too), you can say 男性側に伝えた.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I knew that there had to be some sort of nuance, but I just could not figure out what that was. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem.